# Passing Ajax Request to Django View on Multiple Button Click

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to Pass data to View with two Click events with Ajax Post, everything goes well, when I have only one Button event (click event), but when I added the second click event I'm getting and error

If there is a need of more reference please let me know.

**Template (With Two Buttons and Two dropdowns)**

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control Plottype">
   <option value="1">Line</option>
   <option value="2">Scatter</option>
   <option value="3">Bar</option>
   <option value="3">Barh</option>
</select>
<div class="btn btn-primary getplot1">Plot1</div>

<select class="valueCountCol selectpicker form-control" name="valueCountCol">
    <option>Col1</option>
    <option>Col2</option>
</select>
<div class="btn btn-primary getplot2">Plot2</div>
```

**Ajax POST (in script)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".getplot1").on('click',function () {
    var plottypevalue = $(".Plottype option:selected").text();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/",
      type: "post", // or "get"
      data: {'plot1':plottypevalue},
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}" }, // for csrf token
      success: function (data1) {        
        console.log(data1);
      },
    });
  });

  $(".getplot2").on('click',function () {
    var valueCountCol = $(".valueCountCol option:selected").text();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/",
      type: "post", // or "get"
      data: {'plot2':valueCountCol},
      headers: { "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}" }, // for csrf token
      success: function (data1) {
        console.log(data1);
      },
    });
  });
});
```

**Views.py**

```
if request.POST['plot1']:
  plottypevalue = request.body.unicode('utf-8')
  data1 = plottypevalue
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data1), content_type="application/json")

if request.POST['plot2']:
  valcountcol = request.body.unicode('utf-8')
  data1 = valcountcol
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data1), content_type="application/json")
```

**Error**

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yigadi\PycharmProjects\MLAutoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 76, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'plot1'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yigadi\PycharmProjects\MLAutoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\yigadi\PycharmProjects\MLAutoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\yigadi\PycharmProjects\MLAutoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\yigadi\PycharmProjects\MLAutoProject\MLAP\MLApp\views.py", line 53, in homepage
    if request.POST['plot1']:
  File "C:\Users\yigadi\PycharmProjects\MLAutoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'plot1'
```

Comment: Could you print out the values of ```request.POST['plot1']``` and ```request.POST['plot2']``` to check if they're receiving a value and if they're receiving the right value.

Comment: You can try this ```request.POST.get('plot1', False)```.

Comment: Thanks @jaimish11, I'll try and Post the result here

Comment: It worked. All I have to do is to change ```request.POST['plot']``` to  ```request.POST.get('plot1', False)```

Comment: As @jaimish11 suggested, checked the value of ```request.POST['plot1']``` in view it was "none", and ```request.POST.get('plot1',False)``` was giving the data passed in AJAX Post.

Comment: I will add this as an answer with an explanation so it can be accepted and be available to other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why `request.POST.get()` works:

It would be natural to just use `request.POST['plot1']` at first. However, what happens in this case is that if `plot1` doesn't exist, it will raise a `KeyError` which is what happened in your case.

The solution is to use `request.POST.get('plot1', False)` this method allows you to specify a default parameter to be used if `'plot1` doesn't exist. `False` is the default parameter in this case.